# How to use docker API

Tags: java, docker

I'm using https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java and there's a command that I need to input:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

I put this on the Windows PowerShell and I get this:

> DOCKER_OPTS=-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock : The term 'DOCKER_OPTS=-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (DOCKER_OPTS=-H ...run/docker.sock:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

How can I change the Docker Host IP and port??

Comment: as its a environmental values, use $env:VariableName = 'new-value'    in powershell or SET DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock" in cmd

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`docker_opts: "-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"`